# minikube: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm

Tags: kubernetes, kvm, minikube

What are installed for minikube:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     26406912 Jun 14 12:05 docker-machine
-rwxrwxr-x  1 me libvirtd 11889064 Jun 14 12:07 docker-machine-driver-kvm
-rwxrwxr-x  1 me me     70232912 Jun 14 11:58 kubectl
-rwxrwxr-x  1 me me     82512696 Jun 14 11:57 minikube
```

Trying to start cluster by minikube

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=kvm
Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0614 12:07:39.515994   14655 start.go:127] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ').

 Retrying.
E0614 12:07:39.517076   14655 start.go:133] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ')
```

I am new to kubernetes. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used

$ dmesg | grep kvm
[    2.114855] kvm: disabled by bios
[    2.327746] kvm: disabled by bios
[  120.423249] kvm: disabled by bios
[  222.250977] kvm: disabled by bios
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My update is close to the solution. The solution is to enable virtualization in the BIOS.

1, Power on your PC and open the BIOS.

2, Go to the `security` section and enable virtualization.

Comment: I am on a Virtual Machine which i can only connect via ssh. Any other solution?

Comment: If you are using VM like VMWare follow the following procedure:
https://techgenix.com/vmware-fusion-5-enable-vt-xept-inside-a-virtual-machine-288/

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the kvm package refer package.

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#kvm-driver

```
# Install libvirt and qemu-kvm on your system, e.g.
# Debian/Ubuntu
$ sudo apt install libvirt-bin qemu-kvm
# Fedora/CentOS/RHEL
$ sudo yum install libvirt-daemon-kvm kvm

# Add yourself to the libvirtd group (use libvirt group for rpm based distros) so you don't need to sudo
# Debian/Ubuntu (NOTE: For Ubuntu 17.04 change the group to `libvirt`)
$ sudo usermod -a -G libvirtd $(whoami)
# Fedora/CentOS/RHEL
$ sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $(whoami)

# Update your current session for the group change to take effect
# Debian/Ubuntu (NOTE: For Ubuntu 17.04 change the group to `libvirt`)
$ newgrp libvirtd
# Fedora/CentOS/RHEL
$ newgrp libvirt
```

Comment: Do you have the option of using virtualbox? I was able to run with virtualbox.

Comment: I also have the same issue. @sfgroups no i cant run using virtualbox.